# uuid_generate_random crash when generating 10 million UUID

Tags: c, hash, uuid

I was trying to test [xxhash](http://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) function. So I wrote a simple program that generates UUIDs and pass it to `XXH32` function. Here is my program:

```
#define UUID_LEN 36

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uuid_t id;
    char cid[UUID_LEN + 1];

    int hash_count = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int hash[hash_count];

    for(int i = 0;i < hash_count;i++) {
        uuid_generate_random(id);
        uuid_unparse(id, cid);

        hash[i] = XXH32(cid, UUID_LEN, time(NULL));

        uuid_clear(id);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I pass number of hash generation as argument(`./main 100`). Program works fine but when I pass 1 million it shows: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I installed all debuginfo packages. When I open core file with `gdb` it shows:

```
Reading symbols from /home/m.azimi/projects/testtommy/main...done.
[New LWP 8117]
Core was generated by `./main 10000000'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004008e0 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffe19da598) at main.c:19
19          uuid_generate_random(id);
```

I tried it with `uuid_generate` which doesn't help. I use fedora 19 with completely updated packages. You can download core file from [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!rIUGFaIA!OEqmwHrcdYaeTDOOgtGdDFfqGVg4rw6Xottk9O32BNQ).

**[UPDATE]**

Based on @Tarik comment I changed to `hash[i % 10000] = XXH32(cid, UUID_LEN, time(NULL));` and it is now working fine. Also I'm only saving the generated integer hashes. So memory usage is 10,000,000 * 4 byte = 40MB. Next I changed the program to this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* allocate 10 million 4byte chunk = 40MB */
    unsigned int hash[10000000];

    return 0;
}
```

This is also crashes with core:

```
[New LWP 13593]
Core was generated by `./main'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040068b in main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff244a388c>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff244a3880>) at main.c:9
9   {
```

The new core file can be downloaded from [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!GNEykJhJ!ZAGG41p2bCHug9YNPJJ5lxQaUD5ECbvh0BusJxaJLuA). Why this should happen? Is there any OS level limit? Is this allocating memory from stack instead of heap? Because `unsigned int *hash = (unsigned int *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * 10000000);` works with no problem.

Comment: What is `XXH32`? And btw, a uuid needs 32 bytes not 36.

Comment: @alk `uuid_unparse` man page says: The  `uuid_unparse`  function  converts  the supplied UUID from the binary representation into a 36-byte string (plus tailing '\0') of the form 1b4e28ba-2fa1-11d2-883f-0016d3cca427. `XXH32` is hash function in `xxhash` library. I'm feeding it with string representation of `UUID`.

Comment: Uh yes, you are correct I forgot the dashes.

Comment: The amount of memory used is 37 X 10,000,000 = 370MB. Not much. Yet maybe it's a heap memory issue. Could you test the same code without storing each of the generated UUIDs. Alternatively, you could declare hash[10000] and do hash[i%10000] = XXH32(cid, UUID_LEN, time(NULL));

Comment: The next thing you might want to do is just allocate 370MB in chuncks of 37 bytes and see what happens. I mean just try that without doing any other processing. The goal of the experiment is to confirm that it is a purely memory allocation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I nailed it. use malloc() to dynamically allocate memory from the heap instead of the stack. I remember facing the same problem in the past.